# Decode LZMA2 file with .xz extension using 7zip SDK

Tags: c#, compression, 7zip, lzma

I need to decode .xz file created with 7zip. Compression alghorithm is LZMA2. How should I use 7zip SDK for C# to solve this problem?
I already tried with this code, but it didn't work:

```
var coder = new SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.Decoder();
var input = new MemoryStream(); // filled with byte array of .xz file
var output = new MemoryStream();

// Read the decoder properties
byte[] properties = new byte[5];
zipFile.Read(properties, 0, 5);

// Read in the decompress file size.
byte[] fileLengthBytes = new byte[8];
zipFile.Read(fileLengthBytes, 0, 8);
long fileLength = BitConverter.ToInt64(fileLengthBytes, 0);

coder.SetDecoderProperties(properties); // this throws exception
coder.Code(zipFile, output, zipFile.Length, fileLength, null);
output.Flush();
output.Close();
```

I marked a line which causes exception.

Comment: It seems that .xz decompression is implemented only for ANSI-C. I solved my problem using xzutils binary. I created new process and pipelined compressed input to it.